# My for each loop with animation code for javafx is not executed

Tags: java, animation, javafx

I am learning about how to play animations in javafx and I have encountered a problem when trying to run my code. The problem is that the code for the animation is not compiled. After examining and debugging the program, I found that the for each loop that has the code is skipped while the program is running. I can't figure out, why the code is not compiled and I also researched on internet for the solution to the problem and didn't find any. Please help me with the problem.

Here is the code for the animation:

```
Timeline timeline = new Timeline();

    for(Node circle : circles.getChildren()){
        timeline.getKeyFrames().addAll(new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, // set start position at 0
                new KeyValue(circle.translateXProperty(), random() * 800),
                new KeyValue(circle.translateYProperty(), random() * 600)
            ),
            new KeyFrame(new Duration(40000), // set end position at 40s
                new KeyValue(circle.translateXProperty(), random() * 800),
                new KeyValue(circle.translateYProperty(), random() * 600)
            )
        );      
    }
    timeline.play();
```

Please tell me if any other information is needed. Thank you!

Comment: Create a [MCVE] and [edit] your question to include it - without that we are reduced to just guessing what might be wrong.

Comment: It's does not compile? or not run? two different things. If it's not entering the loop than probably `circles.getChildren()` is returning 0 element.

Comment: Thank you very much @yogidilip, after reading your comment i thought about it and when I looked at my program, I saw that the code for creating the circles was after the animation code. I fixed that and now my program runs successfully.